# Does MAGMA automatically identify $G$ and $G^\text{op}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, magma-cas

Let $G$ be a finite group and $p$ be a prime.

Moreover, let $k$ be a finite field of characteristic $p$, such that $p$ divides $|G|$. Furthermore suppose that $k$ is a splitting field for $G$.

Let $M$ be a $kG$-module.

I wrote the following function in MAGMA and I am wondering what it does.

```
InverseRep:=function(M)
    G:=Group(M);
    f:=Representation(M);
    return GModule(G, [(f(G.i))^-1: i in [1..Ngens(G)]]);
end function;
```

Why is no error message returned (since this is not well-defined because f_new$(g1\cdot g2)\neq$f_new$(g1)\cdot$f_new$(g2)$) ?

But the new rep. is a rep. for the opposite group.

Question:

> Does MAGMA automatically recognize this and somehow identify $G$ and $G^\text{op}$?

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Magma does not check whether your assigned list of images of the group generators extends to a homomorphism, probably because this is not feasible for very large groups, or it might be very time consuming. Even when $G$ is nonabelian, it might extend in some examples, but in others it won't, and the object that you have attempted to define will not be well-defined. Subsequent behaviour is then unpredictable, and might result in a crash.